# Taking screenshot using opengl v2 android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshot of my screen with opengl.And i have been through many resources but i cant understand how and where to add this given support code and also how to call it in my button click function.Can anyone help me with that...

```
if(screenshot){                     
    int screenshotSize = width * height;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
    int pixelsBuffer[] = new int[screenshotSize];
    bb.asIntBuffer().get(pixelsBuffer);
    bb = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixelsBuffer, screenshotSize-width, -width, 0, 0, width, height);
    pixelsBuffer = null;

    short sBuffer[] = new short[screenshotSize];
    ShortBuffer sb = ShortBuffer.wrap(sBuffer);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(sb);

    //Making created bitmap (from OpenGL points) compatible with Android bitmap
    for (int i = 0; i < screenshotSize; ++i) {                  
        short v = sBuffer[i];
        sBuffer[i] = (short) (((v&0x1f) << 11) | (v&0x7e0) | ((v&0xf800) >> 11));
    }
    sb.rewind();
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(sb);
    lastScreenshot = bitmap;

    screenshot = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use overlay like this:

```
    public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1,bmp2 //you can add more you if  want) {
    bmp1 = Bitmapfromopengl;
    bmp2 = Bitmap2;

    bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```